# What is the name of a "headless" bolt

Tags: bolts, terminology

Wasn't sure whether to post this on ELU or here, but thought I would have better luck here.  Anyway Merriam Webster defines a [Stud Bolt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stud%20bolt) as

> a bolt with threads on both ends designed to be screwed permanently
>   into a fixed part at one end and to receive a nut on the other.

Is the first part of the definition - screwed permanently into a fixed part -   always true for a stud bolt?  If so, what do you call the threaded rod that fully penetrates two parts and is attached with a nut on both ends like you would see for piping flanges?

Comment: I call it an “all-thread”.

Comment: I call it "threaded rod".

Comment: In common usage, it is often just a "stud"... many people omit "bolt". E.G. the search for items on Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/ls1-head-studs/s?page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Als1%20head%20studs

Comment: I also call it all thread.+ threaded rod would be correct also but in the trades it is usually called all thread. Portland bolt states all thread is commonly called threaded rod.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Hardhat Engineer](https://hardhatengineer.com/flange-bolt-chart-stud-size/), the correct term to use is *stud bolt*.  While a stud bolt frequently (most often?) is used where one end is screwed permanently into a fixed part, like the dictionary says (think of the stud bolts for a cylinder head), it can also apparently refer to a bolt with a nut on each end as shown below
 [image: Stud Bolt]

I agree that this *looks* like threaded rod, but I do not think that threaded rod is necessarily designed for the stress encountered in a bolting application.

Comment: You can get threaded rod in (metric) grades 8.8, 10.9, and 12.9, same as bolts. It appears you can also get mild steel versions, but I'm not sure on relative availability.

Answer (score 0):

Home Depot calls it Threaded Rod.  I agree: https://www.homedepot.com/s/threaded%2520rod?NCNI-5

Answer (score -1):

Search for "hillman group 44948 hanger bolts" to see if this is the item you are looking for. Then go to Lowes or Home Depot to purchase.